# Saving fingerprint image in sql server 2014 database

Tags: c#

I am developing a finger print system. I want to submit the finger print image and other data such as first name and last name to the database but it keep showing this exception: 
`No mapping exists from object type System.Drawing.Bitmap to a known managed provider native type.`

here is my last code:

```
public void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     @fname = txtfname.Text;
     @lname = txtlname.Text;
     byte[] @img1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(pictureBox1.Image));    
     con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-400N4CL;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");
     con.Open();
     cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.fingerp " + " (fname,lname,finprint) " + " VALUES(@fname,@lname,@img1)", con);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtfname.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtlname.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img1", pictureBox1.Image);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
```

I have used this method as well:

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte2(Image bmp)
  {
     byte[] img1 = new byte[0];
     using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
      {
       bmp.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
       stream.Close();
       img1 = stream.ToArray();
      }
     return img1;
  }
```

with the same error.
Any assistance pls.

Comment: Please note that the database type "Image" is not an bitmap image per se, it's a sequence of bytes, basically a byte array in this context.

Comment: Also note that if the data type in the database is actually "IMAGE" you should use "VARBINARY(MAX)" instead (probably).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save the content of the `PictureBox` (which is of type `System.Drawing.Bitmap`) into a database field which expects binary data.

So the problem is this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img1", pictureBox1.Image);
```

And it should be

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img1", @img1);
```

which is a byte array containing your image data.

I also assume that your `finprint` column is of `BINARY` or `VARBINARY` type.

Comment: Thank you very much. it worked. finprint is varbinary(max). It saved successfully but the finprint field is saving the same value for different individual finger print. Is it suppose to be like that? How can I make it unique pls?

Comment: The image data stored in DB depends on the value of `@img` variable which is getting passed as parameter to your `INSERT` query, so most likely there is a bug in your program. Try to debug `ImageToByte2` method and check the content of `@img` before the query is executed.

Comment: I debug it, put "add watch" and the value before execution was null. I check the individual content of the array. they are still the same. what could be wrong pls?

Comment: That means that every time you call `ImageToByte2` you give it a reference to the same image. Make sure that your program updates `PictureBox.Image` before calling `ImageToByte2(pictureBox1.Image)`.

Comment: so grateful for you help @Alex. I have done it such that pictureBox1.Image = null; after each execution but the the result is still the same. the image value for today is still the same as that of yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL server expects a file stream and your logic in ImageToByte2() method implementation is wrong.

Also, you are trying to pass a bitmap to the database, which will not work.

Try this :

```
public void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
@fname = txtfname.Text;
@lname = txtlname.Text;
byte[] @img1 = ImageToByte2(pictureBox1.Image);
con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-400N4CL;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.fingerp " + " (fname,lname,finprint) " + " VALUES(@fname,@lname,@img1)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtfname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtlname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img1", @img1);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}


public static byte[] ImageToByte2(Bitmap img)
{
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
return stream.ToArray();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. the line  byte[] @img1 = ImageToByte2(pictureBox1.Image); show error underlining imageToByte2 The name 'ImageToByte2' does not exist in the current context How do I correct that please

Comment: I just edited the code. A parenthesis was misplaced in my code.Try now